# How to get data response when Exception produced using the new V107 RestSharp c#?

Tags: restsharp, http-status-code-401

i am using the new RestSharp V107 version with net 5.0.

I am calling a custom Web API. This Web APi, when the request is not authorized responses with an httpcode 401 and this information in the body (extracted from a request made in Postman)

{
"timestamp": "2022-03-30T12:17:18.558462",
"message": "Unauthorized",
"clazz": "com.mycompany.login.service.impl.AuthenticationServiceImpl",
"method": "authenticate",
"lineno": 64,
"path": "/login"
}

With RestSharp v107 i get an exception, with the message "Request failed with status code Unauthorized", but i can't get the data (or the original 401 Unauthorized http code).

I have tried this in the code, with no luck

```
    var optionsbase = new RestClientOptions("http://mycompany")
      {
        ThrowOnAnyError = true,
        FailOnDeserializationError = true,
        ThrowOnDeserializationError = true,
      };
```

Is there any way to get the message in the body when 401 Status is received?
Is there any way to obtain the original message and exception code  (in my code i was catching the exception, chceking the status code 401 and saving the info in the body for log)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the best way is not to force RestSharp to throw but to inspect the response instead. The `RestResponse` object contains the response content and the response code.

That's the code that calculates the exception:

```
                => httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode
                    ? null
#if NETSTANDARD
                    : new HttpRequestException($"Request failed with status code {httpResponse.StatusCode}");
#else
                    : new HttpRequestException($"Request failed with status code {httpResponse.StatusCode}", null, httpResponse.StatusCode);
#endif
```

You can see that when you use .NET Core 3.1+ or .NET 5+, you will also get the status code in the exception, but .NET Standard doesn't support that. You still get the status code in the exception message. However, there's no way to include the response content in the exception.